# Seq2seq embedding with pretrained word2vec

Tags: tensorflow

I know this question has been posted before but looking at the answers I cant figure out how to do this. I want to use pretrained vectors for the encoder inputs in tensorflow seq2seq embedding (the translate example in tensorflow tutorials). 
I know in the core_rnn_cell_imp.py file it initiates the embedding using the following code:

```
embedding = vs.get_variable(
            "embedding", [self._embedding_classes, self._embedding_size],
            initializer=initializer,
            dtype=data_type)
```

But how can I overwrite this embedding with array X:

```
 X = np.ndarray(shape=(20,10), dtype='f') # lets say I want to replace the embedding with this pretrained array

    with tf.variable_scope("embedding_rnn_seq2seq"):
      with tf.variable_scope("embedding_wrapper"):
        sess.run(tf.assign(embedding, X))
```

After I created the model, I ran the above code, just before the training and I get the following error:

```
global name 'embedding' is not defined
```

How should I fix this? Sorry I'm new to tensorflow.

Comment: Is `embedding` defined in the same Python function where you added the new code?

Comment: @mrry --No it's not. Is this why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Yes, that's a Python error because that variable name isn't defined in the same scope. You'll need to find some way to pass the value of `embedding` to the point where you're trying to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just see 
[chatbot.py](https://github.com/Conchylicultor/DeepQA/blob/master/chatbot/chatbot.py)

```
 def loadEmbedding(self, sess):
        """ Initialize embeddings with pre-trained word2vec vectors
        Will modify the embedding weights of the current loaded model
        Uses the GoogleNews pre-trained values (path hardcoded)
        """
……
```

I think this is useful.